# Python Time Filter Not Working

Tags: python, time, filter, gis

I have a script I am using to produce GIS maps. The incidents being mapped are filtered by time of day using an "elif" statement to filter incident data:

```
    elif iHours == 8:
        if x == 0:
            stTime = "00:00:00"
            endTime = "23:59:59"
        elif x == 1:
            stTime = "07:00:00"
            endTime = "14:59:59"
        elif x == 2:
            stTime = "15:00:00"
            endTime = "22:59:59"
        elif x == 3:
            stTime = "23:00:00"
            endTime = "06:59:59"
```

0 through 2 work fine but the script does not work on 3 (23:00:00 - 06:59:59). Here is the IF statement I am using to also filter the data.

```
    "' AND \"Time\" >=  '" +  stTime + "' AND \"Time\" <= '" + endTime + "'"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. clarify question - how it doesn't work, what's error. 2. learn format "and time >= {0} and time <= {1}".format(stTime, endTime)

Comment: You're spanning two days but not including date information, so it's the same as asking for a number that's greater than 23 but less than 7 - nothing will ever pass that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few general tips:

- If you use SQL, try using a decent [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), probably [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).  It will save you a lot of time and trouble.
- A cleaner filter would be `... AND (Time >= 07:00:00 AND Time < 15:00:00)` instead of the `:59:59` hack.

And for the solution: The filter for case #3 should be using OR since a time cannot be both after 23:00 and before 07:00 :

```
... AND (Time < 07:00:00 OR Time >= 23:00:00)
```